# Using 'LIKE' in a join (Replacing CASE with dimension table)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view

I've successfully prototyped a system that is working quite well and it is now time for me to go back and clean some things up before proceeding - as per suggestion from my senior.

In a generic sense, we're using views to only give us customers from one company and group them into one parent company. For example, grouping 'Tesco UK & Ireland' as company 'Tesco'.

I do this with:

```
CASE
    WHEN CustName = 'Tesco UK & Ireland' THEN 'Tesco'
    ELSE CustName
END
```

However, there is one issue with this approach (which works until you need to incorporate the grouping as a dimension table). Some companies have more specific names that if I were to go through all of them would have a case statement worth hundreds of lines; and some other times the customer names aren't being uploaded correctly. Another example with a random company: 'PC World' is what i'd expect, although sometimes I'm given 'Currys PC World', 'PC World Glasgow' and different variations of that. So to combat this I've tried:

```
CASE
    WHEN CustName LIKE 'Tesco UK & Ireland' THEN 'Tesco'
    WHEN CustName LIKE '%PC World%' THEN 'PC World Other'
    END CustName
END
```

However, I was wondering if there is a way to incorporate this in a dimension/mapping table?

Ideally, I'd like to join on CustName to a dimension table and be given the generic name.

Any ideas?

Paul.

Comment: Rather than use CASE statement why don't you add new column to store generic name in table ?

Comment: @KrishnrajRana The data is uploaded from an embed system in factory, we need to transform the data for reporting purposes. It's a hassle, but they want us to change the way we report, rather than having a column that's not used when uploading.

Comment: Case expression, not case statement...

Comment: @jarlh the two are basically the same.. most people understand what it meant when either way is said. Although slight differences.

Comment: @Paul, a case expression returns a value. A case statement is for conditional execution of code (e.g. in a stored procedure), and has no return value.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you maintain a mapping table with two (important) columns, one for the original name and one for the mapped name.  In queries, you would use a `left join`.

Here is an example:

```
create table CompanyNameSynonyms (
    CompanyNameSynonymId identity(1, 1) primary key,
    CompanyName varchar(255) unique,
    MappedName varchar(255),
    CreatedAt datetime default getdate()
);
```

Then a query would like like:

```
select coalesce(cns.MappedName, t.CompanyName) as Name, count(*)
from t left join
     CompanyNameSynonyms cns
     on t.CompanyName = cns.CompanyName
group by coalesce(cns.MappedName, t.CompanyName);
```

You do need to populate this with *all* examples of the alternative names, and then keep the data up-to-date.  However, I consider this a benefit for three reasons.  First, being explicit is usually a good idea for such reports, to avoid unnecessary confusion.  Second, the join using `=` is faster than join using `like` with wildcards.  Third, all the code that uses this table will be updated when the table is updated.

Comment: The problem with this is we don't know all the alternative names that can happen for specific customers.

Comment: @paul You specifically asked to join on CustName to a dimension table.  You have series of incomplete questions.  And a low acceptance count when I can see the stated question is answered.